# How to put an error message on the screen when the file size limit is reached?

Tags: file-upload, liferay, filesize

If I try to upload some file which is exceeding on the limit size..
There are no error message shown on the screen but however, I did find an error message on the logs saying:

```
 03:24:20,890 ERROR [UploadServletRequestImpl:101] org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (220546593) exceeds the configured maximum (104857600)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (220546593) exceeds the configured maximum (104857600)
```

I want to specifically show an error message on my screen saying: `"You've reached the maximum size of 10mb."`

Thanks.

Comment: which liferay portlet you are using?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you give me examples of portlets..I'm really new to this..

Comment: Actually, I already edited the maximum file size in the Server Administration>File Uploads>Maximum File Size...

Comment: Document and Media portlet is the one where you can upload documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you action class you will add your error key along with request object like below,

```
SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "your-error");
```

In your JSP you will add:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<liferay-ui:error key="your-error" message="Your error message goes here!" />
```

Also it could be handled through exception class, With SessionErrors code like,

```
try {
    // ... Code which will throws the exception
} catch(SomeException se) {
    SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, se.getClass().getName());
}
```

In jsp

```
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= SomeException.class %>" message="This is your Error" />
```

Reference link:
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/User+Feedback+-+Success+and+Error+Messages+in+Portlets